# How to prevent enter key on windows console from automatically scrolling

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-console

Whenever I type some characters into the windows console and hit enter, it automatically scrolls to the next line. Is there any way to disable this behavior in C++ (using the Windows API), and if so; how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `scanf` or `getline` or similar then the underlying C runtime (CRT) handles Enter, Backspace, Delete, arrow keys, Tab, and such, and of course all printable keys.

If you want to handle Enter differently from CRT then you will have to handle every other key as well, using `_getch` (nonstandard function different from `getchar`). You will have to write some code. As far as I know there is no way to use `scanf` or `getline`, without Enter going to the next line.

Comment: As far as I know, the functions you mentioned above read console input in much the same way I do (through Win32 API). This doesn't solve the issue, because the problem seems to be with the low-level console input rather than the high-level console character streams.

Comment: @invertedPanda please read the article for [_getch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=vs-2019) on Microsoft Docs. This function will read the character without buffering and without echoing. `getchar` on the other hand reads from the buffer (that requires for user to press `Enter`) and the keypress is echoed. You want to disable that echo, so that `Enter` does not in fact moves the cursor to a new line. That is why you need `_getch`.

Comment: Ah, you are in fact correct. Would you also know of a more low-level version of _getch I can use (i.e. one I can supply a console HANDLE to)?

Comment: Check out [console functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions), `ReadConsole` in particular.